# oracle regexp_replace to remove duplicate duplicate strings and double separators

Tags: oracle, regular-expression

Been using the following regexp_replace to create a comma separated string for those values in '***col_name***' and remove any duplicates.

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E,col_name,',').EXTRACT('//text()')).GetClobVal(),','),'([^,]+)(,\1)+', '\1')
```

Works ok but with 1 exception - if 'col_name' has empty string values. What I am ending up with is:

**value1,value2,,value3,value4,,value5 etc.**

Looking for that elusive regex that can remove any duplicate values and those repeating commas.

Thanks

--- updated ----

col-name
-----------------
row1    value 1
row2    value 2
row3           
row4    value 2
row5    value 3
row6    value 1
row7

**Expected Result**: value1,value2,value3

Comment: Provide some sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would the following be acceptable (not a REGEXP_REPLACE, but maybe easier to understand)?

Test table/data:

```
create table t as
select 'row1' c1 , 'value1' c2 from dual union all
select 'row2' ,  'value2' from dual union all
select 'row3' ,  null from dual union all
select 'row4' ,  'value2' from dual union all
select 'row5' ,  'value3' from dual union all
select 'row6' ,  'value1' from dual union all
select 'row7' ,  null from dual;

select * from t;

C1      C2
row1    value1
row2    value2
row3    null
row4    value2
row5    value3
row6    value1
row7    null
```

Query:

```
select 
  listagg(c2 , ',') within group ( order by c2 ) 
from (
  select distinct c2 
  from t
  where c2 is not null
);

result
value1,value2,value3
```

Dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1c36d4b4c790ac71fcad2539f006b1bb).